# If my product (open source or proprietary) requires Oracle GraalVM to work and bundles Oracle GraalVM, can I charge money for my product?

Tags: licensing

If my product (no matter open source or proprietary) requires Oracle GraalVM to work and bundles Oracle GraalVM, can I charge money for my product?

According to the link of GraalVM Free Terms and Conditions (GFTC) including License for Early Adopter Versions:
https://www.oracle.com/downloads/licenses/graal-free-license.html

> (b) redistribute the unmodified Program and Program Documentation, under the terms of this License, provided that You do not charge Your licensees any fees associated with such distribution or use of the Program, including, without limitation, fees for products that include or are bundled with a copy of the Program or for services that involve the use of the distributed Program.

If I charge users a fee, how do I define whether the fee is associated with my product or Oracle GraalVM?

Comment: This is Law.SE, a GraalVM tag has nothing to do here

Comment: Ok, let me remove it.

Answer (score 1):

> If I charge users a fee, how do I define whether the fee is associated with my product or Oracle GraalVM?

> provided that You do not charge [...] including, without limitation, fees for products **that include** or **are bundled** with a copy of the Program or for services that **involve the use** of the distributed Program.

Your program does envision to bundle the program and the service does involve the use of the distributed Program, so you can't charge anything full stop.